# PyWinAuto issue: can't access header's columns

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, pywinauto

I have some problems with clicking on specific columns of a header in a `list view` using [**pywinauto**](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto).

When I try to click on a specific column it always clicks on the center of the whole header. I checked it using `DrawOutLine()` and no matter which name of header I use, it draws a rectangle over whole Header. See attached print-screen:

[image]

Is there any way I can `Click()` on a specific column?

**EDIT 1:** Swapy proprieties:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Header control has no children controls (every item is a part of the control) but these items can be accessed using `HeaderWrapper`.

Example (click on header item #0):

```
header.click_input(coords=header.get_column_rectangle(0).mid_point())
# or
header.click(coords=header.get_column_rectangle(0).mid_point())
```

Yeah, this looks not so obvious. Sounds like nobody tried to automate a header item click. We can try to improve this API usabilty soon.

P.S. SWAPY is not maintained currently. Hope to re-write it later in a more unified way (to support pywinauto 0.6.0+). [This is a very first prototype](https://github.com/pywinauto/py_inspect) though. :)